# Contradiction ?! Interior of Space filling Curves and Baire Category Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was thinking about and got confused. Is there a contradiction ?

One version of Baire Category Theorem states:

Let $X$ Baire Space and $ {\{F_n\}_{n=0}^\infty} $ a countable colection of closed sets of X  such that $\bigcup \limits_{k=0}^\infty F_n = X$ then $\mathring{{F_{n_0}}} \neq \emptyset $ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$

But a Space Filling Curve $H$ is a map $H:X \to X×X$ that passes through each point of the space. Is interior of that curve empty? Looks like it isn't but I can't imagine that

Comment: How do you define the interior of that curve? There is no "curve" in the image now

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ topological spaces and $f:X \to X$ a curve. I call interior of a curve the interior of $graph\{X\times f(X)\}$ with the topology of $X\times Y$

Comment: What does $graph\{X \times f(X)\}$ mean?

Comment: Also, your question defines a curve to have the form $H : X \to X \times X$ whereas your comment defines it to have the form $f : X \to X$. Which one is it?

Comment: @LeeMosher H is the space filling curve while f is some general curve. Reading now looks like some mess, sorry about that

I call $graph\{X\times f(X)\}$ the set $\{(x,y)\in X\times Y | f(x) = y\}$

, for H  we have: 
$$graph\{X \times H(X)\} = \{ (x,y,z) \in X^3 | H(x) = (y,z) \}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you perhaps confusing the graph of a function with the image of the function?

Let me first talk about the image. The image of a surjective function $H : A \mapsto B$ equals the entire range $B$ by definition, and therefore the interior of the image of $H$ in the space $B$ is equal to $B$.

By any definition, a "space filling" function has the property that it is surjective; that's what it means for the function to "pass through every point" of the range. So the image of any "space filling" function $H : X \to X \times X$ is all of $X \times X$, and therefore the interior of its image in $X \times X$ is all of $X \times X$.

Now let me talk about the graph. The graph of a surjective function $H : A \mapsto B$ is the subset $\{(a,H(a)) : a \in A\} \subset A \times B$. Note that the graph passes the "vertical line test" meaning that it intersects each vertical "line" $\{a\} \times B$ in exactly one point, namely the point $(a,H(a))$. Unless $B$ is a single point, the graph is *not* equal to $A \times B$. Furthermore, if we make a mild assumption that $A$ and $B$ have no isolated points, the interior of the graph is empty.

You should now be able to compare two separate situations regarding a "space filling" map $H : X \to X \times X$. Because these two situations are in separate spaces (first in $X \times X$; second in $X \times (X \times X)$), there is no contradiction.

First, the image of $H$ is a subset of $X \times X$, namely all of $X \times X$, and its interior in $X \times X$ equals $X \times X$.

Second, the graph of $H$ is a subset of $X \times (X \times X)$, and its interior in $X \times (X \times X)$ is empty (under a mild assumption that there are no isolated points).

Comment: +1. An easier picture of the same phenomenon: consider the identity map $id:X\rightarrow X$. Then - assuming $X$ is reasonable - the graph of $id$ (a subset of $X^2$) has empty interior, but the image of $id$ (a subset of $X$) is all of $X$, so clearly has interior $X$.